# Weka can not understand nominal value

Tags: weka

I have nominal attribute to categorize my instances and I create it as follow:

line 15 : @attribute uniqID nominal

but when I try to run classification by using weka Api in java I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: no valid attribute type or invalid enumeration, read Token[nominal], line 15

here is what I have in the header of my arrf file:

```
@attribute advNum numeric
@attribute isLink {0, 1}
@attribute uniqID nominal
```

Am I missing anything?Also if I use string instead of nominal( I just want to give a unique id to some instances for example those that has the same username) do I get the same result?

Answer (score 6):

arff format require possible values of a nominal field are given
as an enumeration at the header. (and **nominal** itself is not a keyword)

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html

> Nominal values are defined by providing an **nominal-specification**
> listing the possible values: {**nominal-name1**, **nominal-name2**,
> **nominal-name3**, ...}
>
> For example, the class value of the Iris dataset can be defined as
> follows:
>
> ```
> @ATTRIBUTE class        {Iris-setosa,Iris-versicolor,Iris-virginica}
> ```

maybe what you need is the string type.